# How to setup model associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I'm trying to create associations for three models in my Rails application. In the application a User can access courses which have videos. How would I model this?

This is what I currently have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :courses
 has_many :videos, through: :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :videos
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :course
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Is this the correct way to model these associations for what I want the application to be able to achieve?

Comment: Can a `video` be used in more than one `course`? Also, you have `belongs_to :user` in `Video`. Is this user the creator of the `Video`? Or, is it any `User` that has access to the `Video` through the `Course`?

Comment: @jvillian Yes each course has several videos. In fact, the courses are video courses. The user does not create the video only accesses it through the course.

Comment: Yes, but (as I asked) can a `Video` be used in many `Courses`? Right now, your `Video` can only belong to a single `Course`.

Comment: Are you asking can the same video be used in many courses? If that is your question no. Each course has distinct videos.

Comment: @jvillian How would I model it where each course would have many videos associated with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this would look something like:

```
class UserCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :course 
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_courses
  has_many :courses, through: :user_courses
  has_many :videos, through: :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_courses
  has_many :users, through: :user_courses
  has_many :videos
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :users, through: :course
end
```

That should let you do:

```
@user.courses
@user.videos
@course.users
@course.videos
@video.course
@video.users
```

(Assuming, of course, you've instantiated each of the above variables and you have associated records.)